# Iterating Over Nullable Error - Checker Framework

Tags: java, checker-framework

I am integrating checker framework to our project. One issue I get is the `iterating.over.nullable`. I am not sure why I get this error since I validate the list using `CollectionUtils.isEmpty()` before accessing the elements of the list.

The list item is `Nullable` but as I understand, since I do the check before accessing, it should not raise the error. Appreciate if someone could point out what I am doing wrong. Below is the code. I get the error `iterating.over.nullable` in line 4.

```
public List<MyCustomObject> map(Delivery delivery) {
    List<MyCustomObject> delList = new ArrayList<>();
    if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(delivery.getDeliveries())) {
        for (MyCustomObject deliveries : delivery.getDeliveries()) {
            //Processing code
        }
    }
    return delList;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

1. Tried with the CollectionUtils.isEmpty since it checks the list is null or empty

Comment: @experimentunit1998X sorry my mistake. It was as you mentioned. Even if it is the case, it raise the issue.

Comment: I think it is raised here. delivery.getDeliveries(). the list is annotated with @Nullable but since I check whether the list is null or not with !CollectionUtils.isEmpty, I am confused why it is raised.

Comment: Perhaps you could try suppressing the warning? https://checkerframework.org/manual/#suppressing-warnings-nullness or conditional nullness https://checkerframework.org/manual/#conditional-nullness

Comment: Yes. Suppressing is the last option and thanks for the suggestion. Still curious though why this happens. Thanks again

Comment: Not sure, but I m thinking that even if you did do a null check with `.isEmpty()` the framework probably doesn't recognize that, so it still thinks you are iterating over a nullable list.

Comment: Yes. I am guessing that too :)

Comment: Can you share whole error stack trace?

Comment: Is there another thread consuming the same delivery object?

Comment: @Hicomputer No this happens at compile time. So cannot be a thread issue. Stacktrace is not available because of that.

Comment: It is hard for me to help cus I can\`t reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Nullness Checker has identified a genuine problem, and the best solution is *not* to suppress the warning.  The problem might be in your code or in your annotations.

Problems like this, and their solutions, are discussed in the Checker Framework manual, in section [Side effects, determinism, purity, and type refinement](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#type-refinement-purity).

In the `if` test, `delivery.getDeliveries()` evaluated to a non-null and non-empty value.  However, there is no guarantee that the second call in the `for` loop *also* evaluates to a non-null and non-empty value.

Therefore, it is indeed possible that, in the `for` loop, `delivery.getDeliveries()` is null and a NullPointerException could occur at run time.

One approach is to extract the expression into a local variable:

```java
Collection<MyCustomObject> allDeliveries = delivery.getDeliveries();
if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(allDeliveries)) {
  for (MyCustomObject deliveries : allDeliveries) {
    // Processing code
  }
```

Another approach is to declare the `getDeliveries()` method as [`@Deterministic`](https://checkerframework.org/api/org/checkerframework/dataflow/qual/Deterministic.html).

Answer (score -1):

if ( delivery != null && !CollectionUtils.isEmpty(delivery.getDeliveries())) {

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).